# how to write strings and numbers to a .txt or excel file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write text and numbers in a text file in matlab, but i am only able to write the numbers easily. I am getting different errors when i try to store strings, as matlab stores strings in matrices in a different format as compared to numbers.

I want to write the file names and corresponding text found in the images in the text file. For e.g. i have an image of 1 digit. My program will identify the 1 text from that image, and it should write in the text file the following line

image1.jpg         1

// and so on

I am only able to write the digits found by my program, i am unable to save the corresponding filenames in the txt file.

THis is the code i have written

```
files = dir('F:\.....path.....\*.jpg');
output_to_write = zeros(size(files,1), 1);
for file = files'
    i = imread(['F:\....path......\' file.name]);


    counter = counter + 1;


    euler_no = regionprops(j, 'EulerNumber');

    if euler_no.EulerNumber == 1
        weights1 = [one(j), two(j), 0, four(j), five(j), 0, seven(j), 0, 0, 0];
        [mx,idx] = max(weights1);
        output_to_write(counter) = idx;
    end

    save output.txt output_to_write -ascii;
```

If i try to make output_to_write a n X 2 matrix and put the file.name at second column for each row of this matrix i get an error. How do i get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `fprintf`?

Comment: No, let me try. Thanks